# this.props.navigation.state.params is undefined in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, parameters, navigation, undefined

I have encounter this problem, where I use same technique on other class component but it works fine.
**Output**
[image]

**Action**
**+ [ItemCreate.js] Parent Class Component**
In this class component I do use `connect()` is there any problem because of `connect()`?
`console.log("STATE PARAMS:", this.props.navigation.state.params.selectedCategory);`

> `STATE PARAMS: undefined`

**+ [ChooseCommerce.js] Child Class Component**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("itemcreate", {
     selectedCategory: "phonesandcomputers"
})
```

Comment: Which version of react navigation are you using?

Comment: React Navigation 4, it is worked on other class component, however even I copied code from my different file, it still have error. But from other class component file that is worked fine I didn't use any connect() method.

Comment: is child class a screen in your navigation ? or is it under parent class which is a screen ?

Comment: Make sure your both screens ChooseCommerce.js, ItemCreate.js must be a part of your navigation screens. If not then passing props between them in your case is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Check the typo inside your project.

If everything correct, using this

```
this.props.navigation.state.params
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way itemcreate.js

```
// 2nd param is "defaultValue"
const selCategory = this.props.navigation.getParam("selectedCategory", "");
```

More details here [React Navigation 4.x Route Params](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/params/)